# How to remove a folder and all its content from the current directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file

This code that does not work:

```
@echo off

if exist output @set /p checkdir= Output directory found. Do you wish to overwrite it?:

if  /I %checkdir% == Y  deltree /s /output 
pause
```

Comment: what problems have you found? DELTREE is not present in many current versions of Windows. Is root the current dir?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You were looking for this command:

```
RMDIR [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path
RD [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path

    /S      Removes all directories and files in the specified directory
            in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove a directory
            tree.

    /Q      Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S
```

In your case just use **/S**
,it will delete the whole directory tree by first asking the user if it should proceed, i.e.- displaying the following output to the screen:

`"folderName, Are you sure (Y/N)?"`

where `folderName` is the name of the folder (and its sub-folders) you wish to remove.

Tested on Windows 7, 64 bit.

Comment: RD works fine. Make sure to add the absolute path or "cd" to the parent directory and just pass the name of the subfolder.